# Assembly language math functions:

Tags: assembly, nasm

For some reason this won't actually go into my other function such as subtraction, division etc. When I enter my numbers into the program it takes them and just prints out the first number that I stored in the system. I may need to fix my control structure maybe? This is supposed to be a simple calculator that takes two numbers and a symbol and gives out an answer. Another question that I have is what is the best way to print the "=" sign after I input my two numbers. 
Thanks,

```
segment .data

segment .bss
num1: resb 4
num2: resb 4
button: resb 2
segment .text
     global  asm_main

  asm_main:
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
; ********** CODE STARTS HERE **********

call read_int
mov DWORD[num1], eax

call read_char
mov DWORD[button], edx
call read_char

call read_int
mov DWORD[num2], ebx

cmp DWORD[button], '+'
je addition

cmp DWORD[button], '-'
je subtraction

cmp DWORD[button], '*'
je multiplication

cmp DWORD[button], '/'
je division

cmp DWORD[button], '%'
jle modulus


addition:
mov eax, DWORD[num1]
add eax, DWORD[num2]

call print_int
call print_nl
jmp end

subtraction:
mov eax, DWORD[num2]
mov eax, DWORD[num1]
call print_int
call print_nl

jmp end
multiplication:
mov eax, DWORD[num1]
mov ebx, DWORD[num2]
mul ebx
call print_int
call print_nl
jmp end

division:
mov eax, DWORD[num1]
mov ebx, DWORD[num2]
mov edx, 0
div edx
jmp end

modulus:
mov eax, DWORD[num1]
mov ebx, DWORD[num2]
call print_int
call print_nl

jmp end
```

Comment: You're still storing DWORDs into `button` where you only reserved space for 2 bytes (a word, not a double-word).  IDK why you want more than 1 byte, or why you're storing it in memory at all instead of a register...

Comment: It should still work the same though right

Comment: Your code has some inconsistency: after your second call to `read_int` the value is passed from `EBX`: `mov DWORD[num2], ebx`, but in your first call it is passed from `EAX`. So does `read_int` return the value in `EAX` or `EBX`? One of them is probably wrong.

Comment: Paul Carter's procedures `read_int`, `read_char` return the result in `EAX`. Additiobnally,  `mov DWORD[button], edx` has to be after the second `mov DWORD[button], edx` (after changing `EDX` to `EAX`.). After the `jle modulus` should be a `jmp end`. Change `button: resb 2` to `button: resb 4`. There are other issues but with these changes the program should run.

Comment: @JayvonJackson: Not necessarily.  If you link with CRT startup code or whatever other object files, and those files put anything in the `.bss`, their functions could be using the bytes from `button+2` onward because the linker merges the `.bss` sections from everything you statically link.  Possibly even writing there in `read_char`

Comment: *"For some reason this won't actually go into my other function"* - what do you mean "for some reason". If you use debugger, you can describe exactly what values and at which instruction - differ from your expectations, and you can't explain them. For some reason it feels like you don't know how to debug assembly... Which makes this type of questions quite futile, as it's about 100x more difficult to program in assembly without debugger (been there, done that, but I was doing it, because I did have access to computer only once a week for 2 hours, so I had to code on paper, and debug myself).

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to debug assembly. That's why I've just been brute forcing it.